# CSS: how do I correctly do this menu?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I am a noob in CSS, and I have searched in some forums the solution to my problem, but I have  found nothing.

When I minimize this page or then I zoom the page (or both), the list items go out from their normal position.

I have 2 divs: 1 at left with the menu and 1 at right with the image. Both are inside the header div.

I would like that these 2 divs inside the header, when I minimize the page and/or zoom it, don't exit from the header div!

This is my CSS code for the 2 divs:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #111122;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
}

#header #logo{
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

#header #nav {
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

ul{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

#header #nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    background: #aabbff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="header">

    <div id="logo">
        <a href="home.html"><img src="images/logo.png" width="200px"></a>   
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="home.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="home.html">CONTACTS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Sorry if the format is not as maybe should be.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you add your HTML? If possible, it would be great to include a working demo of the code as a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Take the height of #header ?

Comment: Sorry if I don't share the images anywhere else: https://www.facebook.com/dru.zod.9889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. But if you're asking how to keep the elements from overflowing their parent container:

1) Remove the fixed `height` from `#header`
2) Add `overflow: hidden` to `#header`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u32HL/

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #111122;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now the header container will always be at least as tall as its content.

### Edit:

If you want the content to "zoom like an image" as the user increases the font size (as mentioned in your comment), then give your container a fixed width:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u32HL/1/

```
#header {
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #111122;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
}
```

However, note that this is **not** responsive. If the user has a lower screen resolution than you set your width to be, your content will go off the screen. Mobile users will see a "zoomed out" version of your website and have to pinch-zoom to read your content.

A much better approach would be to use media queries to make sure your content looks good at every screen width.

Comment: Yes, that is the first thing I wanted. But what overflow does exactly? And if wanted to decide the height of my header?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` does what it says - if the content overflows the box, it will hide it. If you want a fixed height, you can add one, and the container will clip any content that overflows (try it). If no height is specified, the container will stretch to make sure no content is hidden.

Comment: Re: staying inline - you're talking about if the user changes the font size using ctrl-+? You don't have any control over that. If the content doesn't overlap, where else would it go?

Comment: Ok. Thanks! But, for example, if I try to see my page on a phone I don't know how it would look... Maybe the menu overlaps something else or change completely position...

Comment: Should we always use  percentage instead of px to make our wepages more responsive, thus adapting them also for any resolution (phones)?

Comment: For that, you'll want to use CSS media queries to set breakpoints: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/

Comment: I would like that my webpages are like an image, like when you zoom them, the elements inside the images don't overlap the others...

Comment: Can you tell me a very good guide(tutorials) for learning responsive web design? I have searched on the web a good one, which begins from the basic things (of css) to the advanced ones, but I still haven't found it, unfortunately...

Comment: See my edit on the post. For responsive web design, I think the link in my previous comment is a good start. Simply shrink your browser until your content looks bad, then add a media query at that width that makes your content look good again. Then shrink your browser again until you find the next break point. Repeat until your content looks good at all widths.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height from the header, and then create a clearfix CSS class and add that your header, e.g.

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

And change your header html to:

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
```